# Sync iCal with Gmail instead of iCloud

Tags: icloud, ical, gmail, android

I would like to edit my calendar either on iCal (running on my MacBook) or on Google calendar (running on my Samsung Galaxy), and see the calendar updated on the other device.

I gathered that it is not possible to use iCloud for this objective. One must use Gmail. (Feel free to contradict.)

Leaving alone the sync between iCloud and iCal is not good either. I'd like to cancel syncing with iCloud to debug syncing between iCal and Gmail/google calendar. (Right now System Preferences under Mail, Contact & Calendars shows both iCloud and Gmail, and yet I do not see the calendar on Gmail -- or on the Android phone.)

If I cancel the sync with iCloud, most of my history disappears. Thus my question is:

How do I move the calendar entries that I currently have with iCloud to Gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I gathered that it is not possible to use iCloud for this objective. One must use Gmail. (Feel free to contradict.)

Sure, I'll try and contradict!

It's my understanding that [SmoothSync for Cloud Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.icloud&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwib3JnLmRtZnMuY2FsZGF2LmljbG91ZCJd) does this.

> How do I move the calendar entries that I currently have with iCloud to Gmail?

I found a [nice step-by-step summary](http://www.burlapmonkey.com/itips/?p=305) at the amusingly named burlapmonkey.com. I'll summarize:

1. Login to your iCloud calendar at icloud.com.
2. Publicly share the calendar you want to export.
3. Select the updated URL that begins with `webcal://` followed by a cryptic address and copy it.
4. Open a new browser tab/window, paste the webcal address *without loading it* (don't press enter).
5. Change `webcal` in the address to `http`. Load the page.
6. Your browser should now be initiating a download of an `.ics` file which you can later import into a google calendar.
7. Don't forget to stop publicly sharing the calendar.

Comment: It appears to have worked. Now I can use either Google Calendar or S(amsung) Planner on Android. iCal didn't let me keep what it had. It resynced with Google Calendar. On the assumption that the three calendar programs will continue to sync correctly, I will mention that there were only two hiccups. Google Calendar does not import non-ascii characters correctly (umlauts, for example, are not understood), and iCal gets back the incorrect characters. My second minor gripe is that the color scheme for the calendars is lost.